# Colorize console output in Intellij products

Tags: console, intellij-idea

I have a custom script with a default output. I'd like to colorize errors, warnings and infos. There's a way to do that in Intellij products (IDEA, PhpStorm, PyCharm)?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

It has been a while, but in case you are still interested, there is a new plugin for console colorizing: [Grep Console](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=7125).

[image: Colorized build output in IntelliJ]

Works nicely with Intellij 12.
Make sure you **restart IntelliJ** after installing the plugin. After you will see the plugin icon in the top left corner (white-red icon).

Comment: A recent version of the [config file for GrepConsole is available in my dotfiles](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/dotfiles/blob/master/GrepConsole.xml). You can copy or symlink it to `$HOME/.IdeaIC12/config/options/GrepConsole.xml`.

Comment: OP Should change answer ;)

Comment: @JJD can you tell us what advantages your config file provides? The plugin (installed today) seems to work pretty well 'out of the box'.

Comment: @Lambart I added custom colors at that time when I was using Maven as the build system. Since I use Gradle I have not been using GrepConsole at all.

Comment: @JJD OK thanks, I guess I'll have a look into your config, since I use Maven. Maybe there will be something useful. I'm using GrepConsole just to highlight WARN/ERROR-level logging on the console, which it already works great at.

Comment: Support for ANSI coloring in the Grep Console plugin was removed in version 6.4 (feb 2017, IJ 2016+).

Comment: @CMerrill - did not notice, the colorizing still works great (v6.6) ;)

Comment: yeah, colorizing of ANSI still works, but now it is done by IntelliJ  itself only

Answer (score 29):

The colors configurations, mentioned in the other responses, work, if you run a regular application and you set the following VM option:

```
-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS
```

Comment: That`s the best way i want!

Comment: Dint work for spring boot app.

Answer (score 23):

It's not supported right now (at least not for all the run configuration types). Please vote for:

- IDEA-23976 [Add ability to color/highlight console output](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23976)
- IDEA-69880 [Support for colors in console output](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69880)

Console output of the [external tools](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/external-tools.html) is fixed to supports ANSI escape sequences to color text.

Comment: Apparently supported in v14:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69880#comment=27-772011

Comment: @jordanpg This fix is for *Java run configurations* **only** – see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69880#comment=27-772027

Answer (score 17):

Latest IntelliJ, PyCharm and PhpStorm have limited support for console output colorization.

Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Console Colors

[image]

Comment: is there any documentation on how to use these? simply using the escape codes does not produce colors

Comment: @Buttons try to install "Grep Console" plugin and enable in its config page "Enable Ansi coloring"

Comment: This is not from grep console!

Comment: Because of this support Grep Console does not handle ANSI colors anymore – https://github.com/krasa/GrepConsole/issues/39

Comment: This supports only 8 ANSI colors. If you want support for 256 colors please vote on this issue – https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137065

Comment: This doesn't support parsing your own output formats.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using spring boot, use Spring Boot to start your application instead of general application. Color will show up. No need to do anything else. It works for me.

[image: Edit Configuration]

Comment: Is this available on community edition? Doesn't show up for me. I have the Spring Assistant plugin installed.

Comment: @Ixx it is not available for community edition only available for Unlimited edition.