# Regular expression for GrepConsole

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, colorize

What is a regular expression which matches the following strings?

```
[INFO] abcd1234_TCT_ALCATEL_one_touch_995 :   Successfully uninstalled com.example.mapdemo from abcd1234_TCT_ALCATEL_one_touch_995
[INFO] abcd1234_TCT_ALCATEL_995 :   Successfully installed /dev/foo/target/foo.apk to abcd1234_TCT_ALCATEL_995
[INFO] abcd1234_TCT_ALCATEL_one_touch_555 :   Attempting to start com.example.foo/com.example.foo.MainActivity
```

Two expressions would be sufficient: One matching by looking for `... Successfully ...` and another by `... Attempting ...` in the strings.

I want to use it for [colorizing the build output of IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14584030/356895) using the [GrepConsole plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about these two simple ones:

```
.*Successfully.*
.*Attempting.*
```

You could improve them from there. Adding the `:` and spaces maybe:

```
.*:   Successfully.*
.*:   Attempting.*
```

---

**Edit**

Make sure that the pattern is within reach of the search:

[image]

It will work:

[image]

Comment: No, this does not work. I guess because of the colon and spaces.

Comment: @JJD It sure works, you'll just have to increase the `Limit max length of matching` since the words you are searching for are off limit.

Comment: Thanks! It works. It would be nice if it would be possible to **export the settings** so they can be imported into IntelliJ resp. Android Studio or on other computers.

Comment: @JJD The GrepConsole settings seems to be stored in `C:\Users\<user>\.IntelliJIdea12\config\options\GrepConsole.xml`. You may try to copy that file to another computer and see if it works. I am not sure and I haven't tried.

Comment: The same config file works with *IntelliJ 12 Community Edition* and *Android Studio*.  On Ubuntu the paths start with `~/.IdeaIC12/` and `~/.AndroidStudioPreview/...` respectively. Thank you.