# How do you enable colored output in the Run panel?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

When I run our Node project at home, I will get the following output in the Run pane:

[image: Uncolored output]

But at work, the output will be colored. There are only **info** items in that shot, but different log levels would have different colors.

[image: Colored output]

[Colorize console output in Intellij products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420992/colorize-console-output-in-intellij-products) even suggests that this isn't possible (at least not without plugins), but I only installed WebStorm at work recently and don't have any plugins.

I searched through the settings, but I couldn't find an option that would enable/disable this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Console Colors

[image]

Are you using custom schema?
Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Schema name

Comment: Looks like I once made adjustments to Darcula on my home workstation some time in the past and all the ANSI colors are white in my adjusted scheme. Thanks

Comment: For me the console colors seem to be set up find like in your screenshot, but I still don't see colors in the Run panel, only when I run commands from the terminal myself.

Answer (score 2):

For others who are using gradle to manage their run configuration,

you need to add the following line to your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.console=rich
```

see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50504295/5198805)

I was developing a plugin using the :runIde command, and installing Grep Console was not enough, as it couldn't identify the 'non-rich' output coming from gradle.

Comment: Using Gradle Wrapper `5.5.1`, this only works if the line is added to `./gradle.properties` in the root folder, where the `gradlew` script is located.