# Colorize output in Intellij IDEA "Run tool window"

Tags: intellij-idea

I already saw how you can customize colors of the console output of Intellij IDEA [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420992/colorize-console-output-in-intellij-products#20942316) but I want to have the same behavior in the `Run tool window`.

For example, when I hit `clean` on a module in the Maven tool window in the project lifecycle (see picture)

[image]).

the whole progress is being displayed in a `Run tool window` (pic below). How can I get those `Console colors` to work with the `Run tool window`?

[image]

This is how terminal window looks like:

[image]